# django: NoReverseMatch для нового объекта

Tags: python, django

Используется Django 1.10.4. У меня есть модель Stream, для которой я создал CreateView. При создании объектов через админку всё работает нормально, однако когда я пользуюсь формой CreateView, объект создаётся (ни в админке ни в БД никаких отличий от других), но попытки указать ссылку на него через DetailView приводят к ошибке:

> NoReverseMatch at /
>   Reverse for 'detail_stream' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'pk': 17}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P[0-9])/$', 'streams/(?P[0-9])/$']

Эта ошибка возникает при выводе ListView, причём только для объекта, созданного через CreateView.
Место где возникает ошибка:

```
{% for item in stream_list %}
    <a href="/streams{% url "detail_stream" pk=item.id %}">
    ...
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

При попытке перейти непосредственно на DetailView (http://127.0.0.1:8000/streams/17) возникает ошибка 404.
urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import StreamList, StreamDetail, StreamUpdate, StreamCreate, ChannelList, ChannelDetail, ChannelUpdate, ChannelCreate, autocomplete, search, filter, follow, follow_list, following_online

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', StreamList.as_view(), name='streams'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9])/$', StreamDetail.as_view(), name='detail_stream'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9])/update/$', StreamUpdate.as_view()),
    url(r'^add/$', StreamCreate.as_view(), name='new_stream'),
    url(r'^channels/$', ChannelList.as_view()),
    url(r'^channel/(?P<pk>[0-9])/$', ChannelDetail.as_view(), name='detail_channel'),
    url(r'^channel/(?P<pk>[0-9])/update/$', ChannelUpdate.as_view()),
    url(r'^channels/add/$', ChannelCreate.as_view()),
    url(r'^autocomplete/$', autocomplete),
    url(r'^search/$', search),
    url(r'^search?limit=(?P<limit>[0-9])/$', search),
    url(r'^filter/$', filter),
    url(r'^follow/$', follow),
    url(r'^following/$', follow_list, name='following'),
    url(r'^following_online', following_online)
]
```

Также url для стримов добавлены в основной urlpatterns сайта.
View:

```
class StreamForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stream
        fields = ('streamer', 'name', 'date_start', 'channel', 'tags', 'logo')
        widgets = {'streamer': HiddenInput}


class StreamCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    form_class = StreamForm
    model = Stream

    def get_initial(self):
        streamer, _ = Streamer.objects.get_or_create(user_id=self.request.user.id)
        return {'streamer': streamer }

    def get_form(self, form_class=None):
        form = super(CreateView, self).get_form(form_class)
        form.fields['channel'].queryset = Channel.objects.filter(Q(owner__user=self.request.user) | Q(streamers__user=self.request.user))
        form.fields['tags'].widget = SelectMultiple()
        return form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        regex = re.compile('[^a-zA-Z]')
        newtags = []
        for tag in form.cleaned_data['tags']:
            tag = regex.sub('',tag)
            newtags.append(tag)
        form.cleaned_data['tags'] = newtags
        return super(StreamCreate,self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(form.errors)
        return super(StreamCreate,self).form_invalid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('streams')
```

Я подозреваю что я что-то не учёл в CreateView, но не могу понять что.
Ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717961/6757293

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ найден здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41717961/6757293, дело в паттерне

`url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9])/$', StreamDetail.as_view(), name='detail_stream`')

который подходит только для pk с одной цифрой, и нужно добавить '+':

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', StreamDetail.as_view(), name='detail_stream`')
```